# Cypress seems to target the wrong element

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

When selecting elements by id using `cy.get()` and then typing into them using `.type()` the wrong element is typed into. This happens intermittently in a number of tests I have written. The `get` seems to select the correct element, but then the `type` inputs in a different one.

Example:
[element correctly selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjlEG.png)
[value entered into wrong element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQNwL.png)

Ive tried a number of things here. `cy.get('#elementid').clear().type('new text')` was how I used to do this, but changed to `cy.get('#elementid').type('{selectall}new text')`. The new method causes this issue to happen far less often, but it still does.

The complete command used in the example screenshots is using a loop to build the element IDs, but this issue also appears when selecting elements without a loop.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('new_supplier_preisanfrage', (customerFullName, discount, priceList) => {
    cy.open_supplier_preisanfrage_dialog(customerFullName)
    cy.get('#1917240871_' + (priceList.length - 1) + '_price').should('exist').then(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i < priceList.length; i++) {
            var price = priceList[i]
            cy.get('#1917240871_' + i + '_price').type('{selectall}' + price)
            cy.get('#1917240871_' + i + '_discount').type('{selectall}' + discount)
        }
    }).then(() => {
        cy.get('#price-inquiry-edit-save-btn').click()
    })
})
```

You can see here that I also tried using `.then()` to wait until all the fields have been loaded into the DOM.

So, How do I debug this further? Is this a known issue? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How about you use something like - `cy.get('selector').clear().focus().type('new text', {delay: 20})`

Comment: Gave it a go. Using this method the incorrect element is still selected intermittently. Adding waits and delays does reduce the chance of it happening, but never completely. With a 200ms wait the chance of this selection mistake occurring seems to be very low (1/~1000).